# SQL add rows count from a second table to the main query

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to improve a (not so much) simple query:

- I need to retrieve every row from Table A.
- Then join Table A with Table B so I get all the data I need.
- At the same time, I need to add an extra column with the count() from Table C.

Something like:

```
SELECT a.*,
       (SELECT Count(*)
        FROM   table_c c
        WHERE  c.a_id = a.id) AS counter,
       b.*
FROM   table_a a
       LEFT JOIN table_b b
              ON b.a_id = a.id
```

This works, ok, but in reality, I'm just making 2 queries and I need to improve this so it only do one (if, its even possible).

Anyone knows how can I achive that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest approach is likely to just move the correlated sub-query into a sub-query.

NOTE: *Many optimisers deal with correlated sub-queries extremely effectively. Your example query could be perfectly reasonable.*

```
SELECT
  a.*,
  b.*,
  c.row_count
FROM
  table_a   a
LEFT JOIN
  table_b   b
    ON b.a_id = a.id
LEFT JOIN
(
  SELECT
    a_id,
    Count(*)   row_count
  FROM
    table_c
  GROUP BY
    a_id
)
  c
    ON c.a_id = a.id
```

Another Note: *SQL is an expression, it is not executed directly, it is translated into a plan using nest loops, hash joins, etc.  Do not assume that having two queries is a bad thing.  In this case my example may significantly minimise the number of reads compared to a single query and then use of `GROUP BY` and `COUNT(DISTINCT)`.*

Comment: SQL Fiddle (originally by @X.L.Ant, added to by me):  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f8177f/15

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT
    tmp.*,
    SUM(IF(c.a_id IS NULL,0,1)) as counter,
FROM (
    SELECT 
        a.id as aid,
        b.id as bid,
        a.*,  
        b.* 
    FROM 
        table_a a 
    LEFT JOIN table_b b 
        ON b.a_id = a.id
) as tmp
LEFT JOIN table_c c 
    ON c.a_id = tmp.id
GROUP BY
    tmp.aid,
    tmp.bid
```

Comment: If more than one line references the same a_id on tables b or c, the result will be incorrect, which seems to be the case, otherwise there would be no point counting them.

Comment: Same problem : b can have more than one row referencing the same id in a. So you might have more than one row with the same a_id in your query, resulting in counting the same c rows multiple times

Comment: @X.L.Ant I've updated the query grouping by id from a and b, without a sub'query i don't know if it can be done

Comment: I see, but it doesn't change anything. As long as b is involved, you'll potentially have multiple references to a, therefore multiple rows.

Comment: @X.L.Ant i get you point but i count the rows from c for each unique combination of aid and bid so it should be the same as the initial query...

Comment: No, in the OP query, it only count c rows for every value of a only