# JOIN Many table while GROUP BY and COUNT the GROUP BY row in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, count

I have table  like this in my database

**lp_kon**

```
ID | lpkonName
1  | kon1
2  | kon2
```

**lp_seb**

```
ID | ID_lpkon | lpsebName
1  |    1     |  seb1
2  |    2     |  seb3
```

**lp_rek**

```
ID | ID_lpseb | lprekName
1  |   1      | rek1
2  |   1      | rek2
```

**lp_tl**

```
ID | ID_lprek | lptlName
1  |    1     | tl1
2  |    1     | tl2
```

I used this query to join these 4 tables

```
SELECT
    a.id as id_lpkon,
    b.id as id_seb,
    c.id as id_rek,
    d.id as id_tl
FROM `lp_kon` a 
left OUTER JOIN lp_seb b  ON a.id = b.ID_lpkon
LEFT OUTER join lp_rek c  on b.id = c.ID_lpseb
LEFT OUTER join lp_tl  d  on c.id = d.ID_lprek
ORDER by a.id ASC
```

I got a resut like this

```
id_lpkon|id_lpseb|id_lprek|id_lptl|
1       |  1     |  1     |  1    |
1       |  1     |  1     |  2    |
1       |  1     |  2     | NULL  |
1       |  2     | NULL   | NULL  |
2       |  Null  | NULL   | NUll  |
```

How do i count the table row while grouping. like the result below

```
id_lpkon | count(lpkon) | id_seb | count(lpseb | id_rek | count(lprek) | id_lptl | count(lptl)   
1        |     4        |    1   |    3        |   1    |   2          |1        | 1       | 
1        |     4        |    1   |    3        |   1    |   2          |2        | 1       | 
1        |     4        |    1   |    3        |   2    |   1          |NUll     |NUll     |
1        |     4        |    2   |    1        |  NULL  | NULL         |NULL     |NULL     |
2        |     1        |  NULL  |   NULL      |  NULL  | NULL         |NULL     |
```

SO for each row they have a count row for each relation table

**Update with Query**

**Lp_kon**

```
CREATE TABLE `lp_kon` ( `ID` int(11) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, `lpkonName` text NOT NULL ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
INSERT INTO `lp_kon` (`ID`, `lpkonName`) VALUES (NULL, 'kon1'), (NULL, 'kon2');
```

**Lp_seb**

```
CREATE TABLE `lp_seb` ( `ID` int(11) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,`ID_lpkon` text NOT NULL, `lpsebName` text NOT NULL ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
INSERT INTO `lp_seb` (`ID`,`ID_lpkon`, `lpsebName`) VALUES (NULL,`1`,'seb1'), (NULL,`2`,'seb3');
```

**Lp_rek**

```
  CREATE TABLE `lp_rek` ( `ID` int(11) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,`ID_lpseb` text NOT NULL, `lprekName` text NOT NULL ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
INSERT INTO `lp_rek` (`ID`,`ID_lpkon`, `lprekName`) VALUES (NULL,`1`,'rek1'), (NULL,`1`,'rek2');
```

**Lp_tl**

```
  CREATE TABLE `lp_tl` ( `ID` int(11) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,`ID_lprek` text NOT NULL, `lptlName` text NOT NULL ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
INSERT INTO `lp_tl` (`ID`,`ID_lprek`, `lpsebName`) VALUES (NULL,`1`,'tl1'), (NULL,`1`,'tl2');
```

Comment: if you mean to count them all separately, I see `sum()` as an answer, but if you want individual counts, you should do it as a series of correlated sub-queries instead of the join, correlate it on the foreign keys ( that might work )  You have to understand that count is an `aggregation` function, and generally will return 1 row, unless using group by.

Comment: this is a fairly good example, however it wont be easy ( with that many tables ) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17105523/sql-add-rows-count-from-a-second-table-to-the-main-query  It may be better to do them separate, I was working on a query at work and it wound up being 9 joins, 3 unions and 4 sub queries, I think I will just do them separately on monday ... lol

Comment: thanks! for the refference https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17105523/sql-add-rows-count-from-a-second-table-to-the-main-query

this is what i looking for @ArtisticPhoenix

Comment: @gagntous sure thing, good luck!

Comment: i want to clear the misunderstood with the question i asked.I want to know is how many row that each id have been looped, for example id_lpkon has id 1&2. id_lpkon 1 loop four times, it will count how many row has been looped inside column count(lpkon), while id_lpkon 2 only loop once, and so other column beside them. id_seb have 1&2. Id_seb 1 looped 3 times, and id_seb 2 only looped once. I read sum() doc, and seems like it calculated the value by adding specific row with other. not calculated how many row that has been looped ( please correct me if i was wrong with the definition of `sum()`)

Comment: Please add CREATE and INSERT statements for your sample data. Do your part to solve the problem. Help others to help you.

Comment: I have added some query for CREATE and INSERT. please check it out 
@PaulSpiegel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this problem is easier to solve with PHP.

Use your query and fetch your data into an associative array. I should look like this:

```
$dbData = [
    ['id_lpkon' => 1, 'id_lpseb' => 1,    'id_lprek' => 1,    'id_lptl'  => 1],
    ['id_lpkon' => 1, 'id_lpseb' => 1,    'id_lprek' => 1,    'id_lptl'  => 2],
    ['id_lpkon' => 1, 'id_lpseb' => 1,    'id_lprek' => 2,    'id_lptl'  => null],
    ['id_lpkon' => 1, 'id_lpseb' => 2,    'id_lprek' => null, 'id_lptl'  => null,],
    ['id_lpkon' => 2, 'id_lpseb' => null, 'id_lprek' => null, 'id_lptl'  => null,]
];
```

Now use a nested foreach loop to count all fetched values:

```
$columns = ['id_lpkon', 'id_lpseb', 'id_lprek', 'id_lptl'];
$counts = [];
foreach ($columns as $column) {
    $counts[$column] = [];
}

foreach ($dbData as $row) {
    foreach ($row as $column => $value) {
        if ($value === null) {
            continue;
        } elseif (isset($counts[$column][$value])) {
            $counts[$column][$value]++;
        } else {
            $counts[$column][$value] = 1;
        }
    }
}
```

You could stop here since you already have the needed data in the `$counts` array, which looks like this:

```
$counts = [
  'id_lpkon' => [1 => 4, 2 => 1],
  'id_lpseb' => [1 => 3, 2 => 1],
  'id_lprek' => [1 => 2, 2 => 1],
  'id_lptl'  => [1 => 1, 2 => 1],
];
```

But if you need the data in one "table", use the next nested foreach loop:

```
foreach ($dbData as $rn => $row) {
    foreach ($row as $column => $value) {
        $countColumn = $column . '_count';
        if ($value === null) {
            $dbData[$rn][$countColumn] = null;
        } else {
            $dbData[$rn][$countColumn] = $counts[$column][$value];
        }
    }
}
```

Demo: http://rextester.com/XQTSX69507

Answer (score 0):

I believe that `sum()` is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I believe since he wan'ts it each time he needs to count a value for each one.

COUNT(table) AS Header,
a.ID AS id_lpkon,
COUNT(table) AS Header2,
b.ID AS id_seb,

etc etc